# Further reading on a unique aspect of scientific paradigms

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-science, reference-request, kuhn

In *the Structure of Scientific Revolutions* Kuhn makes an off-hand remark that it seems like, in science, paradigms achieve a near-universal acceptance that rarely happens in non-scientific fields. This is especially evident when the first scientific paradigm emerges, as Kuhn points out that Newtonian mechanics and the first theory of magnetism united labs across the world who were working on different projects under a unified umbrella of inquiry. We can easily come up with contrastive examples of fields where paradigms develop and compete with each other, such as deontological vs virtue vs consequentialist ethics in philosophy.

Are there any authors who have seriously investigated the idea that this unifying character and universal acceptance of the paradigm is closely connected to what it means for inquiry to be scientific? I'm not convinced that I buy the strong version of this claim (that universal acceptance is characteristic of science) but I would be very interested in reading various accounts or analyses of the idea.

Comment: See [Imre Lakatos](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/lakatos/), [Historicist Theories of Scientific Rationality](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/rationality-historicist/), [Scientific Progress](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/scientific-progress/), [Larry Laudan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larry_Laudan), [Thomas Nickles](https://www.unr.edu/philosophy/philosophy-people/thomas-nickles) for comments and debate.

Comment: The spelling of words in the English language is pretty universal, and that's not a scientific example.

Comment: We can read Kuhn against the so-called [demarcation problem](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/pseudo-science/#ThoKuh): the "dogmatic" adoption of the paradigm and the ensuing *normal science* is what accounts for progress and rationality. This is not so for art, philosophy, etc. where we see many "revolution" but not progress in the sense of "accumulation of knowledge".